# Designing a unified response object - java

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am designing a unified response object for REST services application , so that the client always expect the same structure, be it an exception is thrown, a simple status is returned, a map of keys and values or a complex DTO.
The idea is that in any of the above case , I want to wrap the response in an object that contains a message , response time and other general info .. here is what I did , and I want feedback from the experts here, if this is the best approach , is there any better approach that follows a known design pattern for the problem, does this design has a drawback and if this design follow any of the known design patterns :

```
@Data
public class StandardResponse{

public static int STATUS_RESPONSE = 1;
public static int DTO_RESPONSE = 2;
public static int MAP_RESPONSE = 3;
public static int SINGULAR_RESPONSE = 4;
public static int EXCEPTION_RESPONSE = 5;

protected Date responseTime;
protected String message;
protected int responseType;
protected Object containedObject;

public StandardResponse() {
    responseTime = new Date();
}

public StandardResponse(String message, Object containedObject, int responseType) {
    this();
    this.message = message;
    this.containedObject = containedObject;
    this.responseType = responseType;
}

public static StandardResponse createStandardResponse(int responseType, Object input) {
    return createStandardResponse(responseType, input, null);
}

public static StandardResponse createStandardResponse(int responseType, Object input, String message) {
    StandardResponse response = null;
    Object containedObject = null;
    if(STATUS_RESPONSE == responseType) {
        containedObject = new StatusResponseDTO((Boolean)input);
    }else if(DTO_RESPONSE == responseType) {
        containedObject =  input;
    }else if(MAP_RESPONSE == responseType) {
        containedObject =  input;
    }else if(SINGULAR_RESPONSE == responseType) {
        Map<String,Object> singularValue = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        singularValue.put("value", input);
        containedObject = singularValue;
    }else if(EXCEPTION_RESPONSE == responseType) {
        //TODO
    }
    response = new StandardResponse(message,containedObject,responseType);
    return response;
}
```

}

Why I didn't go the simple way of making a super class `StandardResponse` and inheret all other types from it ? because in case of returning Map or Exception I wont be extend `StandardResponse`

Comment: Seems reasonable to me.

Comment: Is it possible to make such serializable objects typesafe?

Comment: @Basilevs ... kindly check my response to Greg's answer (if I understand your question correctly)

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a perfect use case for generics or class templates.

```
public class StandardResponse<T> {
    private T message;

    public StandardResponse(T message, int responseCode) {
        this.message = message;
        // ...
    }

    public T getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Now your responses can be tailored to whatever you want:

```
try {
    BlogPost = new BlogPost(...);

    // Save to database

    return new StandardResponse<BlogPost>(blogPost, 200);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    return new StandardResponse<Exception>(ex, 500);
}
```

With this, you can sub class StandardResponse to further clarify your code and its intent:

```
public class ServerErrorResponse extends StandardResponse<Exception> {
    public ServerErrorResponse(Exception exception) {
        super(exception, 500);
    }
}

public class ResourceNotFoundResponse extends StandardResponse<String> {
    public ResourceNotFoundResponse(string message) {
        super(message, 404);
    }
}

public class SuccessResponse<T> extends StandardResponse<T> {
    public SuccessResponse(T message) {
        super(message, 200);
    }
}
```

And using it feels more RESTful:

```
try {
    BlogPost postToEdit = // get from database

    if (postToEdit == null) {
        return new ResourceNotFoundResponse("Blog post not found");
    }

    // edit and save to DB

    return new SuccessResponse<BlogPost>(postToEdit);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    return new ServerErrorResponse(ex);
}
```

Comment: nice but I have two concerns that make me think it won't fit well, first, I will need to move the logic inside the if -conditions to the response client (i.e. duplication and mixing concerns)  .... second I will still need to pass the response type integer in order to distinguish types of reaponses (ex, : Exception repsonse versus normal) so it will be mix of generic / hard typed .... or other wise I will need another way to distinguish (may be check using typeof which is not clean) ... If u think I am wrong please correct me

Comment: @Greg's answer is basically what frameworks like Spring do. Whether you think Spring Framework is a good reference or not, is up to you to decide, but its approach is more Object oriented than yours. Your approach is feated to gather a huge technical debt in the mid/long run.

Answer (score 1):

Overall looks ok, but since you posted here to get some feedback, here's what I'd usually mention in my code reviews.

- the convention is that if you declare constants (considering your variables are in uppercase, I presume they are constants) they should be declared as 'static final'
- I'd recommend to make those constants private as well
- the class has a sort of a 'factory method' (createStandardResponse), so the question is - do you need to access your constructors from outside of the class? If not declare your constructors private (or protected, looking at protected variables it looks like you want to extend it)
- *StandardResponse response = null;* - is redundant, you can just do *return new StandardResponse(...)*
- Replacing multiple *if/else if* with *switch* statement will make it more readable
- *new StatusResponseDTO((Boolean)input)* - doesn't look safe, maybe worth checking instanceof before casting, or if possible send input as String and then do Boolean.valueOf(input)
- And please-please-please use LocalDate instead of Date (hopefully it's Java 8) :)

Comment: P.S. my answer is not exactly design related, because there's not really much to discuss, it's just one class :) And I couldn't put it under comments as well because SE doesn't allow me yet commenting